How to transform nested data to be used with an tabular learning network
I have an dataframe containing measurements and error with there corresponding status and counter. And i want to use it to feed it into e.g. TabNet
Raw dataframe



protocolid
time
measurement_1
measurement_2
Error_id
Error_status
Error_counter




ABC
12:34:45
15
0.1
[AB123,CD456]
[Active, Passive]
[3 , 1]


EFG
54:32:10
22
0.5
[AB123,CD456,GH654,PO237]
[Active, Passive, Passive, Active]
[5, 1,2,1]



I made a new feature for the Error id where i created a binary number with every position of of the number represents a place in a lookup table. And the Status i also changed into an binary number which has as many digits as there are error codes. Now I dont know how i could flatten the other array (Error_counter) because i dont always have the same amount of error per entry.
Lookuptable = {
 0:AB123,
 1:CD456,
 2:EF465,
 3:GH654,
 4:PO237
} 

Raw dataframe



protocolid
time
measurement_1
measurement_2
Error_id_bin
Error_status_bin
Error_counter




ABC
12:34:45
15
0.1
11000
10
[3 , 1]


EFG
54:32:10
22
0.5
11011
1001
[5, 1,2,1]



